# How to send language string in email message body

Tags: wp-mail, language

I am using wp_mail() function to sending email. I have one static string "Hello Admin". My clients wants convert this string to language string. So it possible to convert static string to language string while sending email.

What I have done so far, please refer my below code.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = get_bloginfo('name').' - Publish Details';
$message  = _("Hello Admin,",'text-domain');
$message .= "$current_user->user_login has published details. Details are as following.\r\n";   

wp_mail($admin_email,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

Output:

```
John has published details. Details are as following.
```

I am not getting language string in email. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, the function is `__()` with two underscores. You will also need to configure the textdomain 'text-domain' and have a valid translation for the end users' browser settings for it to not default to english.

```
// use two underscores in the method
$message  = __("Hello Admin,",'text-domain');

// assuming this is a plugin and your language files are in a /languages subdirectory
function load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'text-domain', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_textdomain' );
```